# should I set this table use FTS format?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, full-text-search

all
  I want to create a table like this, it will be store about 100,000 rows, it not often do write operation. update the all table about 1 day once or 1 week once. I think may be use FTS format will be better,or may be we can use sqlite instead mysql , but I am not sure, so I post here. hope your suggestion.

```
create table if not exists info (
`dev_id` char(16) unique primary key,
`type_cpu` mediumint unsigned,
`type_mem` mediumint unsigned,
`type_stroge` mediumint unsigned,
`type_position` int unsigned,
`type_floor` mediumint unsigned,
`type_room` mediumint unsigned,
`type_machine` mediumint unsigned,
`type_use` mediumint unsigned,
`dept`  mediumint unsigned,
`project`  mediumint unsigned,
`group`  mediumint unsigned,
`status` mediumint unsigned,
`payed` mediumint unsigned,

key (`type_cpu`)
key (`type_mem`),
key (`type_stroge`),
key (`type_position`),
key (`type_floor`),
key (`type_room`),
key (`type_machine`),
key (`type_use`),
key (`dept`),
key (`project`) 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answer so I close it.
in those days , I get my answer, I post here , and hope can help peoples has same issue like me .

FTS table will treate all data as text, so in above example, this table maybe reference other tables in feature. so the best Optimization idea I think we can split table, one table contains lots index. another use to storage data and only have a primary key.